# How to get a variable to bind from xhr call response in VueJS?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, xmlhttprequest, axiom

Ok I'm a beginner at VueJS and I'm just trying to do a simple XHR call and bind the json data response to my variable...

I have a component App.vue and this part of the template I want to show the results of the json. bpi is the name of the variable

```
<div id="simulationPoints">
    <h2 className="logTitle">Full Log:</h2>
    {{ bpi }}
</div>
```

then my script

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    bpi: []
  }),
  mounted: () => {
    axios.get(`https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.jsonp?start=2011-01-01&end=2018-02-01`)
      .then(response => {
        this.bpi = response.data.bpi
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. I'm using Axiom to fetch the data and assign the response, and this is how all the examples I found online did it, but the array object I have is still empty and it doesn't render on the page. I don't know whats the issue here? A Vue expert please help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are sorts of problem in your code.

First, don't use arrow function on options property or callback since arrow functions are bound to the parent context, `this` will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect.

Second, use `return` statement in your data function.

Third, use `created` hook for inserting data after instance is created. `mounted` hook is called for mutation after DOM is rendered.

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: function() {
    return {
      bpi: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get(`https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.jsonp?start=2011-01-01&end=2018-02-01`)
      .then(response => {
        this.bpi = response.data.bpi
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
  }
}
```